# Bootstrap Hamburger

Tags: html, css, navbar

Currently I have a navbar set up however when I shrink the tab to tablet size, the navbar stacks and looks really weird. However, when I shrink all the way to mobile the problem is fixed. What is the best way to determine when the navbar shrinks to hamburger? Ideally for me, this would be as soon as the navbar headings begin to stack themselves.

Comment: Add some code to your question. Nobody is going to be able to help if we can not identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bootstrap just check the width size when it shrinks to mobile with Google inspect,

If the `@media` query triggers at e.g 500px just add some more pixels so it triggers when you need it to, for example if the navigation bar stacks and looks bad at 700px, change the `@media`query size from 500px to 700px.

(That was just an example , because you did not post any code)

Comment: So I would create my own @media style in CSS, or use the one provided in bootstrap? And what would the code look like if I wanted it to trigger at say 500px.

Comment: I need you to share your code so I can help you better, what I wrote before was an example. And you could do both modify the bootstrap to fit your needs but usually create your own class to modify it and apply it at !important , I would look for something like this http://imgur.com/a/6UdsX , and then add a custom class to your custom css file and change the size adding the !important method.. Again this an example since I don't have your code.

Comment: Thats along the lines of what I have been trying but doesn't seem to be doing the trick. The nav Bar I am Using is like such: <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">